# Display percentage value in Pie Chart

Tags: java, sql, jfreechart

I did the coding to create a pie chart file in `png` format file; the pie chart shows the percentage, but it's in the bottom of the file. I want the percentage to appear in the chart itself. This is the code I have used:

```
String query = "SELECT name,flag from mawarid";

JDBCPieDataset dataset = new JDBCPieDataset(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ 127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "", "");

dataset.executeQuery(query);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
    "Test", dataset, true, true, false);
try {
    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setLegendLabelGenerator(
        new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {2}"));

    final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(
        new StandardEntityCollection());
    final File file1 = new File("Chart5.png");
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // log exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same message format in a label generator as you do in your legend label generator:

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {2}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`PieLabelDistributor`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PieLabelDistributor.html) on the `PiePlot`.

```
plot.setLabelDistributor(PieLabelDistributor aDistributor)
```